# How to add "blog" slug to wordpress posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working on wordpress project that i have one diffuculty, i want to add "Blog" slug to blog posts

for example 
my current blog slug is like

```
http://www.abc.com/post
```

i want to make it like

```
http://www.abc.com/blog/post
```

i don't want to create custom post type i need to use existing ones

i have tried many solution such as changing permalinks to blog/%postname%

one solution worked for me

below is my code

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_default_post_type', 1 );
function my_new_default_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'post', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
        ),
        'public'  => true,
        '_builtin' => false, 
        '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'blog' ),
        'query_var' => false,
        'with_front' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
}
```

i have added this code to my functions.php and added slug to posts. but problem came when i clicked on particular post it will redirected to 404 page. and if i remove this code it i will redirecting to correct post.

need your suggesions.

Comment: Just calling your attention to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (which you may not have seen yet); a moderator will probably move your question.

Comment: You could use an Apache rewrite rule to remove the /blog/ in the requests?

Comment: i actually dont know how it works

Answer (score 7):

just go to your permalink settings make sure you have it set to custom and add "/blog/" in front of %post_name% this way you'll have "/blog/" in front of your structure, if you also use CPT make sure that you add 'with_front'=>false when you register them like this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cpt_name', 'with_front'=> false ),
```

the way it works is: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will be: 
if with_front = false  permalink: /news/
if with_front = true   permalink: /blog/news/

and the issue is that it defaults to true

the wordpress codex page that has this info is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

what you also have to note is:
If registering a post type inside of a plugin, call flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation and deactivation hook (see Flushing Rewrite on Activation below). If flush_rewrite_rules() is not used, then you will have to manually go to Settings > Permalinks and refresh your permalink structure before your custom post type will show the correct structure.

Answer (score 1):

One way is creating a category called `blog`, and assigning your posts to that category. That way, the default `/category_name/post_name/`style permalinks will show.

Comment: this solution is not useful in my scenario :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is right with just a slight change you need to add 'with_front' => false in your "rewrite". here is the combined code...

add_action( 'init', 'custom_url_post_type', 1 );
function custom_url_post_type() {

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Post', 'add new on admin bar' ),
    ),
    'public'  => true,
    '_builtin' => false, 
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d', 
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'query_var' => false,
    'with_front' => false,
    'rewrite'    => array( 
        'slug' => 'blogs',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats' ),
) );
```

}